# Managing browser window focus

Tags: browser, cross-browser, focus, window

- Parent window opens a child window.
- User toggles to Parent window.

Can a button/link in the Parent window bring the child window into focus? (I tried a quick and dirty test and it worked in Safari in OSX...and it works) Will this work across [Grade A browsers](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/#gbschart)?

If the parent window is closed...

Can another window target the child and bring it into focus?  Can another window close the orphaned child window?

Comment: what language are you using? javascript? can you clarify (and tag) ta!